# Do we need to use padding parameter for inferencing in Bert?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to inference through Bert model. I have tokenized my input using the padding parameter during training as shown below.

encoding = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(data,padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=150, return_tensors="pt")

However, during inferencing I tokenized my input without the padding parameter and it still worked for me. The only change I noticed was the time taken in inferencing which got reduced.

So, I need to know that how Bert is able to predict without padding as the input length would be inconsistent for all the datapoints.

Any information on this would be really helpful.

Without the padding parameter I was expecting Bert to throw an error but it ran successfully.

I need to know how is this happing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to generating padded matrix of tokens, the tokenizer provides the input attention maps with the same shape (only zeros and ones). All padded tokens get zero attention, so the padded embeddings get masked (multiplied by zero) therefore they have no effect on the output.

You need padding when you have input sequences of various lengths in one batch. If you can afford running with batch size = 1 there is no need for padding.

An example of batch_size=2:

```
batch_sents = [
    ["[CLS]", "It", "rains",   "[SEP]", "[PAD]"],
    ["[CLS]", "It",    "is", "raining", "[SEP]"],
]
attentions = [
    [1,1,1,1,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1],
]
```